# mysql query execution time forced hosting side to block database

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

database of my website has been blocked by hosting side...
they said you queries has been taken too much time to execute...the message has been send by them is:

```
    This message is to advise you of a temporary block placed on your database. The database "**DATABASE NAME**" was found to be consuming an inordinate amount of processor time, to the point of degrading overall system performance. While we do limit each account to no more than 25% of a system's CPU in our terms of service, we do not actively disable accounts until they greatly exceed that number, which is what happened in this case.

Running Processes:
fastlynx 26884 0.3 0.0 0 0 ? ZN 23:26 0:00 [php] <defunct>

Running Queries:
*************************** 1. row ***************************
USER: USERNAME
DB: SB_NAME
STATE: optimizing
TIME: 40
COMMAND: Query
INFO: SELECT * FROM price WHERE country LIKE '27'/*--*/and/*--*//*!30000if(ascii(substring((user()),11,1))<121,BENCHMARK(151973069.6,MD5(0x41)),0)*//*--*/and/*--*/'x'='x%' GROUP BY country ASC order by country asc limit 0, 12
*************************** 2. row ***************************
USER: USERNAME
DB: DB_NAME
STATE: optimizing
TIME: 54
COMMAND: Query
INFO: SELECT * FROM price WHERE country LIKE '27'/*--*/and/*--*//*!30000if(ascii(substring((user()),4,1))<122,BENCHMARK(151973069.6,MD5(0x41)),0)*//*--*/and/*--*/'x'='x%' GROUP BY country ASC order by country asc limit 0, 12
```

From above it seems like that queries from a single table are taking max execution time...
i already have optimized all table in database through mysql control panel.
Guys..Help me to handle this situation.
Thanks in advance....

Edit :

Actual queries are as:

```
SELECT * FROM price WHERE country LIKE 'G%' GROUP BY country ASC limit 0, 12
                               OR
SELECT * FROM price WHERE prefix LIKE '91%' GROUP BY country ASC limit 0, 12
```

AND one thing more that....m also using NOT LIKE some times as lika that :

```
SELECT * FROM price WHERE country LIKE 'G%' AND country NOT LIKE 'INDIA%' GROUP BY country ASC limit 0, 12
```

[image: Database Table Price screen shot]

Comment: We are NOT the support services of your host.

Comment: @jocelyn i wrote my problem here...and need help to resolve my proble...not asking for support services.

Comment: How long does these single queies take IF you query them manually from let's say phpMyAdmin or similar?

Comment: Can you please supply us with some code that shows how at least one of these queries are generated in php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean with "optimized"? If you already did that, we can't do anything anymore for you.

But considering you use `WHERE country LIKE '27'` you didnt optimize that much. If the country is always an integer value, make sure country has a numeric datatype and that you put an index on it. Also query it with `WHERE country='27'`, because a `LIKE` statement doesnt use the index but will do a full table scan. (If you have 1000 rows, every single time that query is executed, all these 1000 rows will be loaded into memory and checked.)

Also since you use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER` on country, so make double sure there is a proper index on this column.

But since the other part of your query is `if(ascii(substring((user()),11,1))<121,BENCHMARK(151973069.6,MD5(0x41)),0)` you can forget about a quick query. That little dragon will be a b*tch on a large table.

Since I dont know which part of that is dynamic and what is static, I can't realy provide optimization improvments. Perhaps give us some insights on what you are trying to accomplish so we can help define a better database structure.

**Update:**

Your query seems strange. Take the last one for example. You are selecting all countries starting with `G` and then canceling countries that start with `INDIA`. Last time I check the `I` is not a `G`, so the second part is useless and only adding overhead.

```
SELECT * FROM price WHERE country LIKE 'G%' AND country NOT LIKE 'INDIA%'
```

Now i dont know how many countries you have in your table, but unless your adding some on another planet, there can't be more then ~200. And with 200 records you can run almost any query without running into problems.

I also notice that you use `GROUP BY` on country, which would imply that countries are in the list several times. But since you use `SELECT *` and dont have any `AGGEGRATE FUNCTIONS` in there like `SUM` or `COUNT`, I would expect there is only one record of each country.

Taking all things in to account, this seems like a very bad design pattern and without knowing what you want to do with the data I cannot help you. Try to provided at least the following

- What field from `SELECT *` are you planning on using, considering the group by?
- What is the prefix? is it a numeric column or some sore of code? What do you expect in return when you use `LIKE '91%'`? countries with prefix '91' and '916'? or just '91'?
- Are countries in the table more then once?

**Update 2:**

The screenshot makes things more clear. Since you are showing all information based on country (which is actually country + provider)  I would make the following changes:

- Drop the prefix column from this table and create a seperate table for the prefix with a link to the auto_id field in this table.
- Add a unique index on the country column (and thus drop all duplicates). then you can select without GROUP BY if you dont need the prefix.
- if you often select all countries starting with a single letter, add another column as char(1) and add the first letter of the country to that column on adding/updating a row. Put an index on that column and then you can select using `SELECT * FROM price WHERE newcol='G'`. You can still add the second part (NOT LIKE) if needed.
- If you have a search function on country column, look into using [FULL TEXT INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/full-text-search.html)

Comment: Hugo Delsing, this is result send by the hosting side, Originally country is of varchar(255) datatype

Comment: Then give is your query. How did you expect optimization if you give us the wrong data? Provide your code on the query and what datatypes you use

Comment: i have added screen shot of table..for your understanding.

Comment: country field can contain repeat country name but different prefix.
and  LIKE '91%' mean i was displaying record that have prefix started with '91XXXX'.
AND group by country is using to display countries without repeatin because in results i dont want to show prefix